# Solving trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry

I am having trouble finding the solution to this equation. I keep getting a negative answer when I know it must be positive as t is time in the problem.

I want to solve $d(t)= 3.5\cos((\pi/6)t)+4.5$ such that $d(t)$ equals $3$.

Comment: Looks like your room mate just posted the same question. Never re-ask the same question. That's against the rules.

Answer (score 1):

$$3.5 \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{6}t\right)+4.5 = 3$$
Subtracting $4.5$ from both sides: $$3.5\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{6}t\right) = -1.5$$
Dividing $3.5$ from both sides:$$\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{6}t\right) = -\frac{3}{7}$$ 
Find the $\cos^{-1}$ (also known as $\arccos$) of both sides:$$\cos^{-1}\left(\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{6}t\right)\right) = \cos^{-1}\left(-\frac{3}{7}\right)$$
Simplifying: $$\frac{\pi}{6}t = \cos^{-1}\left(-\frac{3}{7}\right)\approx 2.0137$$
Multiplying both sides by $\dfrac{6}{\pi}$: $$\boxed{t\approx 3.8459}$$